# Can phone_home module be used multiple times in cloud init?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, init

The cloud-init in ubuntu (and other distros) have:
(https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#phone-home)

```
phone_home:
url: http://example.com/$INSTANCE_ID/
post:
    - pub_key_dsa
    - instance_id
    - fqdn
tries: 10
```

Is it possible to call multiple hosts (urls with this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. [`phone_home`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#phone-home) is meant to run once per instance, and send the information to a single URL. If you need to send the information to multiple places, you'd need to introduce a proxy that can fan out the http call to multiple locations.

Comment: Will try to use [runcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#runcmd) and post result.